# Server shutdown hangs (when oss/lynxtwo driver does not load properly)

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, shutdown, audio, hangs

I have re-installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 in my server used primarily for audio via OSS driver (v4) with LynxTwo card.
It worked well for few days but then the reboot/shutdown started to hang (had to power off manually). When I restart, the oss driver does not load the sound device.
To make it work, either I have to reboot multiple times and remove the audio jack from the server just before powering it down.
Note, when it hangs, the console says Powering off or Rebooting but the audio device (DAC) still indicates its locked to the Ubuntu server.
ANY HELP WILL BE MUCH APPRECIATED PLEASE

Below is the last bit of the kernel message during startup when the oss driver does NOT load ok:

```
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.436868] Hardware name:  /DG41MJ, BIOS MJG4110H.86A.0006.2009.1223.1155 12/23/2009
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.436902] RIP: 0010:init_lynx_hal+0x24/0x3f0 [lynxtwo]
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.436946] Code: 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 41 55 66 0f ef c0 41 54 55 53 48 89 fb 48 81 ec 28 01 00 00 48 c7 47 18 00 00 00 00 48 8b 7f 10 <0f> 29 04 24 0f 29 44 24 10 0f 29 44 24 20 48 c7 44 24 30 00 00 00
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437023] RSP: 0018:ffffbecf009a7838 EFLAGS: 00010292
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437049] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffbecf00945010 RCX: ffff991f4393ef88
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437081] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff991f4393ee00 RDI: ffffbecf00955000
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437113] RBP: ffffbecf00945010 R08: 0000000000000073 R09: 0000000000000000
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437146] R10: 0000000000000196 R11: ffffffffffffffff R12: 0000000000000000
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437177] R13: ffffbecf00945060 R14: ffff991f41add0d0 R15: ffff991f54e98368
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437210] FS:  00007f3c02e23c40(0000) GS:ffff991f7c680000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437247] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437274] CR2: 00007f75cbb2f560 CR3: 000000000f518000 CR4: 00000000000406e0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437306] Call Trace:
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437322]  <TASK>
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437335]  ? mutex_lock+0x13/0x50
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437359]  ? __setup_irq+0x3fd/0x780
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437383]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x19e/0x2e0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437409]  ? request_threaded_irq+0x112/0x180
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437432]  ? uninit_lynx_audio+0x130/0x130 [lynxtwo]
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437470]  ? oss_register_interrupts+0xb0/0x130 [osscore]
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437524]  ? lynxtwo_attach+0x255/0x4b0 [lynxtwo]
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437557]  ? pci_enable_device_flags+0x104/0x170
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437585]  ? oss_cdev_compat_ioctl+0x20/0x20 [osscore]
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437625]  ? osspci_probe+0x99/0x150 [lynxtwo]
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437659]  ? local_pci_probe+0x4b/0x90
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437682]  ? pci_device_probe+0x119/0x1f0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437704]  ? really_probe+0x222/0x420
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437727]  ? __driver_probe_device+0x119/0x190
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437752]  ? driver_probe_device+0x23/0xc0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437777]  ? __driver_attach+0xf7/0x1f0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437799]  ? __device_attach_driver+0x140/0x140
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437825]  ? bus_for_each_dev+0x7f/0xd0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437848]  ? driver_attach+0x1e/0x30
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437869]  ? bus_add_driver+0x148/0x220
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437891]  ? vunmap_range_noflush+0x3d5/0x470
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437917]  ? driver_register+0x95/0x100
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437939]  ? 0xffffffffc0e59000
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437957]  ? __pci_register_driver+0x68/0x70
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.437982]  ? pcidrv_init+0x23/0x1000 [lynxtwo]
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438015]  ? do_one_initcall+0x49/0x1e0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438038]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x19e/0x2e0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438063]  ? do_init_module+0x52/0x260
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438085]  ? load_module+0xb2b/0xbc0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438107]  ? __do_sys_finit_module+0xbf/0x120
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438131]  ? __x64_sys_finit_module+0x18/0x20
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438155]  ? do_syscall_64+0x5c/0xc0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438179]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x37/0xb0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438206]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438232]  ? __x64_sys_mmap+0x33/0x50
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438253]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438275]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438296]  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x1e7/0x670
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438320]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x37/0xb0
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438346]  ? irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x9/0x20
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438373]  ? irqentry_exit+0x1d/0x30
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438394]  ? exc_page_fault+0x89/0x170
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438416]  ? entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438443]  </TASK>
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.438457] Modules linked in: lynxtwo(OE+) osscore(OE) binfmt_misc coretemp serio_raw at24 mac_hid sch_fq_codel dm_multipath scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua pstore_blk msr efi_pstore ramoops pstore_zone reed_solomon ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear gpio_ich i915 i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops cec rc_core psmouse i2c_i801 pata_acpi i2c_smbus lpc_ich r8169 drm realtek video
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.440507] ---[ end trace 8df845ec2de9027e ]---
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.442386] RIP: 0010:init_lynx_hal+0x24/0x3f0 [lynxtwo]
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.444143] Code: 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 41 55 66 0f ef c0 41 54 55 53 48 89 fb 48 81 ec 28 01 00 00 48 c7 47 18 00 00 00 00 48 8b 7f 10 <0f> 29 04 24 0f 29 44 24 10 0f 29 44 24 20 48 c7 44 24 30 00 00 00
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.446006] RSP: 0018:ffffbecf009a7838 EFLAGS: 00010292
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.447865] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffbecf00945010 RCX: ffff991f4393ef88
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.449731] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff991f4393ee00 RDI: ffffbecf00955000
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.451666] RBP: ffffbecf00945010 R08: 0000000000000073 R09: 0000000000000000
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.453508] R10: 0000000000000196 R11: ffffffffffffffff R12: 0000000000000000
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.455299] R13: ffffbecf00945060 R14: ffff991f41add0d0 R15: ffff991f54e98368
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.456959] FS:  00007f3c02e23c40(0000) GS:ffff991f7c680000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.458638] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 17 02:08:35 vortexbox kernel: [   37.460312] CR2: 00007f75cbb2f560 CR3: 000000000f518000 CR4: 00000000000406e0
Jun 17 02:10:52 vortexbox kernel: [   62.998214] loop5: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
```

Answer (score 0):

When a driver crashes, 99% of the time the system is unable to reboot properly. Unfortunately you're confronted with a driver or hardware bug, so there isn't much you can do. (the crash seems to occur during the HAL (hardware abstraction layer) initialisation stage, pointing towards a hardware problem).

You should probably power off the machine instead of doing a soft reboot, because obviously the hardware isn't properly reset after the driver crash. If it worked properly for a while and you didn't upgrade, I'd try if possible with another card of the same model to sort out potential hardware trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went ahead and re-installed Ubuntu. The sound card/driver is working again but it did clocked/popped a couple of time. I feel the issue will back again after a few days or week. Is there a way to uninstall the physical sound card driver (similar to Device Manager removing devices in Windows) and re-install it? (I have been re-installing the OSS drivers but that does not solve the problem). Thanks

Comment: I also noticed the server's signal to my DAC get lost when switching some other electrical  equipment in the house. I suspect the  clicks/pops are related to some power usage of the Lynx card

Comment: @Ditusade you can unload the driver (apparently it's named lynxtwo?) : `modprobe -r lynxtwo, however your DAC problem sounds 100% like there's something fishy with the hardware.

Comment: thanks will give it a try

Comment: Hi, Tried modprobe -r but got the "module is busy" error. Investigated more and tried blacklisting, rmmod, rmmod -f,  update-initramfs -u, etc... None allowed to unloading the module. Tried "install module /bin/true" in the blacklist did work but I could not reload the module manually.  Reset my config and after 8 shutdowns, the modules loaded ok. I know if i shutdown, the offending modules (osscore, lynxtwo) will fail again. Any other ideas if you have please?

Comment: From this page: http://manuals.opensound.com/devlists/lynxtwo.html the driver may not be compatible with the latest firmwares. Check that your card's firmware matches your driver version. Also the page clearly states that "unsolvable problems" occur with this hardware and driver...

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update, the OSS and Lynxtwo drivers load fine every time. Its only the Lynx card does not occasionally recognise the audio dac device.
I noticed if I remove the LAN cable before rebooting, the drivers load fine with the audio DAC recognised (most of the time).This is my current workaround but is annoying as I have to remove the LAN cable then hook it again after.
Is there a way to force the network drivers load to trigger after the oss/Lynx drivers get loaded successfully? Thanks